# Battery Charging and Discharging rate

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, discharge, discharging

I did some calculations for hybrid renewable energy system and I calculated the energy from PV and Wind. Then I modeled a battery for both the PV and the Wind energy systems.

I found that energy production is 720 kWh less than the electrical load, so battery discharges and 855 kWh of battery capacity is reduced in providing that 726 kWh.

I need to find the discharging rate of the battery.

Can you please help me in that?

How can I find the discharging rate with the data given above?

Comment: We are missing some information about time / duration of discharge...

Comment: The duration is one hour. So hourly step function.
PS energy production is 726 kWh less than the electrical load not 720